# Calling a bash script with a header parameter camel-exec

Tags: bash, apache-camel

I have a route that looks like this:

```
from("direct:start") .to("exec:bash?args=testScript.sh")
.log("Process done.");
```

This route runs fine. But now I need to call the script with a parameter that is an exhange header.

So, I tried:

```
.to("exec:bash?args=testScript.sh ${header.testHeader}")
```

But instead of running the script with the actual value of the header (an integer), it runs the script with the string "${header.testHeader}".

In my script, I am building a directory. The header value Im passing in makes the directory look like this:

```
testDirectory/${header.testHeader}
```

Rather than:

```
testDirectory/882
```

I know the header value is set correctly because if I do:

```
.log( "${header.testHeader}")
```

I get the value of the header that I expect to see (i.e.882).

Does anyone know how to call exec with a shell script and use the actual header value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the to() endpoint is not dynamic.  i.e. it isn't evaluated for every new exchange, just once at start up.  Camel 2.16.0 introduced the [toD()](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html) endpoint which is dynamic. Alternatively if you're on an earlier version you can use [recipientList()](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) which is also dynamically evaluated. In java DSL that would be something like this :-

```
from("direct:start").recipientList().simple("exec:bash?args=testScript.sh ${header.testHeader}");
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that about .to. I'm using Camel 2.15.5 (in case anyone else comes across this), and second solution using recipientList().simple... worked like a charm.